# Excel-Fill series with prime numbers

Tags: excel

At first i don't know English very well, sorry about this. Then i work the problem on Excel 2010

My problem is that want to fill series with prime numbers, in other words when pull cell down, they fill with prime number. Tried custom lists but it didn't work, cell fills irrelevant value.

How can i do that? Is there any formula to fill series?

Comment: The problem is not to fill series is to fill the series with prime numbers. You should create a udf vba function to get the next prime number after a given prime and then call that function in the worksheet as a formula...

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is there anyway doing that without vba? And after create udf, excel fill cells with prime number when pull down?

Comment: I dont see any way without vba, yes if the function returns the next prime you can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create these 2 functions in a module in VBA:

```
Function Prime(ByVal x As Long) As Boolean
Dim d As Long, raiz As Long
If x <= 3 Then
 Prime = x <> 1
Else
 If x Mod 2 = 0 Then
  Prime = False
 Else
  d = 3
  raiz = Int(Sqr(x))
  Do While (d < raiz) And (x Mod d <> 0)
   d = d + 2
  Loop
  Prime = x Mod d <> 0
 End If
End If
End Function

Function NextPrime(ByVal x As Long) as long
 x = x + 1
 If x Mod 2 = 0 Then x = x + 1
 Do While Not Prime(x)
  x = x + 2
 Loop
 NextPrime = x
End Function
```

Now in Excel write, for instance, the value 7 in A1 then write in A2:

=NextPrime(A1)

Copy down and you have a list of prime numbers starting at 7